# GoogleSheet ImportFeed only unique Headlines

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

IMPORTFEED("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q="Sony")

I'm query google news for the keyword "Sony" and in the IMPORTFEED formula, I want to only bring back unique headlines. I want to exclude duplicate headlines even if they are published by different news outlets.

For example, if the "New York Times and the New Yorker Magazine both published the headline "Sony is Awesome" then I want the IMPORTFEED to bring back only 1 of those headlines and it doesn't matter which publisher it wishes to use.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(IMPORTFEED("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q="Sony"))
```

Comment: How do I excluded specific publisher from the results? For example, I don't want any headlines from "New York Times"

Comment: @HelpMePlease you can use query: `=QUERY(UNIQUE(IMPORTFEED("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q="Sony")); "where not lower(Col1) contains 'new your times'")`